# Using beautifulsoup to scrape <h2>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nltk

I'm trying to scrape the text of a specific 'h2', but I keep getting this error when i use .text or .get_text. what should i do?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.ocupacoes.com.br/cbo-mte/251205-economista'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.find_all('h2')[1])

and i got this : <h2>Descrição Sumária</h2>
```

but i would like to receive this
"Descrição Sumária

Analisam o ambiente econômico; elaboram e executam projetos de pesquisa econômica, de mercado e de viabilidade econômica, entre outros. participam do planejamento estratégico e de curto prazo e avaliam políticas de impacto coletivo para o governo, ong e outras organizações. gerem programação econômico-financeira; atuam nos mercados internos e externos; examinam finanças empresariais. podem exercer mediação, perícia e arbitragem."

and when i use text or get.text i get this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `next_sibling`.

```py
text = soup.find_all('h2')[1].next_sibling.string

print('\n'.join(text[idx:idx+80] for idx in range(0, len(text), 80)))
```

```
Analisam o ambiente econômico; elaboram e executam projetos de pesquisa econômi
ca, demercado e de viabilidade econômica, entre outros. participam do planejamen
to estratégicoe de curto prazo e avaliam políticas de impacto coletivo para o go
verno, ong e outrasorganizações. gerem programação econômico-financeira; atuam n
os mercados internos eexternos; examinam finanças empresariais. podem exercer me
diação, perícia e arbitragem.
```

Note, I've used a list comprehension to print the text solely to limit it to 80 characters to make it more readable.

This means some words will be split

Answer (score 0):

The solution from [norie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69903497/15164646) working but at the slightest change may break due to hardcoded `for in range()`

You may want something like this ([example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Using-beautifulsoup-to-scrape-lessh2greater#main.py)):

```py
text = soup.select_one('#container-principal > section > h2:nth-child(11)').next_sibling.strip()
print(text)

'''
Analisam o ambiente econômico; elaboram e executam projetos de pesquisa econômica, demercado e de viabilidade econômica, entre outros. participam do planejamento estratégicoe de curto prazo e avaliam políticas de impacto coletivo para o governo, ong e outrasorganizações. gerem programação econômico-financeira; atuam nos mercados internos eexternos; examinam finanças empresariais. podem exercer mediação, perícia e arbitragem.
'''
```

---

P.S. There's a [dedicated web scraping blog](https://dev.to/dimitryzub) of mine. If you need to parse search engines, have a try using [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.